# MVC Kendo UI Notification widget not showing when called from Ajax success function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

ASP.Net MVC 5, Kendo 2015.3.1111.545

The Kendo helper code:

```
@(
    Html.Kendo().Notification()
    .Name("popupNotification") 
    .AppendTo("SalesGrid")
)
```

In the function that gets called and in turn sets up an ajax call.  Within the success block, we do this

```
success: function (result) {
    var statementBatchDS = $('#SalesGrid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource;
    statementBatchDS.data(result.Data);

    //test
    var popupNotification = $("#popupNotification").data("kendoNotification");
    popupNotification.show("Batch post error", "error");
}
```

However, my notification never shows up

[update]
Hold on!  it is actually showing, it's just that it goes away as soon as the grid has finished re-binding.  What I need to happen is to show a notification that stays up for a specific amount of time AFTER the grid has finished binding, based on a condition of some of the data that is being returned.  This data is in the "result" parameter in the code snippet above.

Comment: You have it being appended to the `SalesGrid` which appears to be a `Grid`.  I'd recommend having it append to a different element, such as a `div`

Comment: ive tried that also.  I think the problem lies in how the notification works and the fact that the grid refreshing seems to interfere with any popups after it starts to databind.   I can pop a simple alert before the datasource is set, but not after

Comment: Wait a tic!  It is actually working, but it fades away as soon as the grid finishes data binding.  Just noticed it in a tiny area on the lower right of my page.  I need to review the attributes im setting, maybe the time setting.